# Capturar mas de un click desde un button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo el siguiente codigo.

Este es el codigo HTML.

```
<form action="" method="post">            
        <div class="row">
            <article class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 aboutBox">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-div-2 clearfix col-lg-3">
                        <h7><b>Contraseña </b></h7>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="tx_Kzk2NUQtQyxWODYtQyxWJGAKYAo=" id="id-psw" placeholder="Contraseña"  maxlength="100" autofocus   > 
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="hd_index_objElement" id="id-hd-index"  value="tx_Kzk2NUQtQyxWODYtQyxWJGAKYAo=,tx_Kzk2OUI4MzhULTMlQS1DJGAKYAo=" maxlength="100" autofocus   > 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-div-1 clearfix col-lg-3">
                        <h7><b>Re Contraseña </b></h7>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="tx_Kzk2OUI4MzhULTMlQS1DJGAKYAo=" id="id-repsw" placeholder="Re Contraseña"  maxlength="100" autofocus   > 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-div-1 clearfix col-lg-2">
                        <h7><b>&nbsp;</b></h7>
                        <div id="generar">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-generar" name="btn-generar" id="id-btn-generar" value="Generar" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#id-btn-generar").on('click', function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/admin/jq/get-jq-pswd-generar.html/",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#generar").html(data['html']);
                    $("#id-psw").val(data['psw']);
                    $("#id-repsw").val(data['psw']);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

El problema es que despues del 1er click, ya no se captura mas el evento. Haciendo pruebas le quite el codigo ajax donde ejecuto el script que devuelve el password generado. No entiendo como solo cargar ese script deshabilita la captura del evento.

Alguna ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido, adjunta el html al que haces referencia en el codigo js

Comment: Si, por favor incluya el HTML para poder entender como está construido y poderle dar solución

Comment: Ya puse el codigo HTML. Hay dos caja input donde se pone el PSW generado desde el button **id-btn-generar** que es el que lanza el evento **click**. Yo lo que pretendo es que se puedan generar tantos PSW seguidos como el usuario quiera.

Comment: De hecho, el primer click genera correctamente lo que quieres ?

Comment: Si. Sin ningun problema. Yo incluso hice lo siguiente. Quite todo el codigo que esta ahi y deje solo un `alert('Si');` y cada vez que daba click me sacaba la ventana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya esta solucionado. Obvie que una vez lanzado el primer click, el Element del DOM se recargaba desde el script php. Cambie el js de la siguiente manera:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#id-btn-generar', function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/admin/jq/get-jq-pswd-generar.html/",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#generar").html(data['html']);
                $("#id-psw").val(data['psw']);
                $("#id-repsw").val(data['psw']);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema no es el evento, sino que el ajax se llama de forma Sincrónica (es decir se aguardara hasta que termine la petición).

Si quieres enviar múltiples peticiones (de forma Asincrónica) con el click debes cambiar.

```
async: false,
```

por

```
async: true,
```

Con lo cual podrás hacer los clicks que quieras

Comment: Lo siento pero hice el cambio y sigue en lo mismo.

Comment: Intenta refrescar la pagina con Ctrl + F5.